# how will DNS work under this circumstance (when no domain name specified)

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, ip

Supposingly there is a host/server in the network with FQDN as "host1.example.com"

Can i know what will happen when i on another workstation, do a 
"ping host1"  assuming that host1 is not recorded in my "/etc/hosts" file.

q1) Will my workstation still try to resolve "host1" by sending a dns query to the DNS server (e.g. 192.168.1.1) ?

q2) In the DNS server, will this query be accepted ? or fall into/being look up in any default zone (e.g example.com) ?

Is there anyway that i can configure my DNS server to have a default zone that is being lookup for unqualified name (e.g. host1)

Regards,
Noob

Comment: Lookup `Connection-specific DNS Suffix Search List` in `ipconfig` at a cmd prompt.

Comment: are these machines a member of active directory?

Comment: @keltari yes they are. how do i set a default zone in the DNS for those query without domain name ?

Answer (score 0):

**q1) Will my workstation still try to resolve "host1" by sending a dns query to the DNS server (e.g. 192.168.1.1) ?**

host1 is a NetBIOS entry but not a DNS entry, DNS entry should have a doamin and a extension parameters.

**q2) In the DNS server, will this query be accepted ? or fall into/being look up in any default zone (e.g example.com) ?**

If DNS server gets NetBIOS request usually this will fail because it don't have a extension.

**Is there anyway that i can configure my DNS server to have a default zone that is being lookup for unqualified name (e.g. host1)**

On internet connection settings you can configure DNS suffix, hence host1 will be auto suffexed with the domain.local before this reach DNS server.

Hence DNS server should receive this as host1.domain.local --> this will solve the issue.

Comment: Do you mind explaining more about NetBIOS , what actually it is ?

Answer (score 0):

How it resolves :
When you enter **ping host1** your PC will append the domains from your suffix list to try and make it a fully qualified domain name. This is normal behaviour but it requires that you have your domains set up in the suffix list. This is usually set up on DHCP as an option.

If you're setting it up manually, you can override your network settings and add the suffix domain list. In linux this is called 'search domains' and can be entered in /etc/resolv.conf